# Mysql query on 2 or 3 tables

Tags: mysql

```
|              ds               |   
|sales_id|    date_issued       |
|    1   |  2016-11-30 01:00:00 |
|    2   |  2016-11-30 02:00:00 |
|    3   |  2016-11-30 03:00:00 |

|             dsr                         |
|  dsr_id | quantity |   date_returned    |
|    5    |    1     | 2016-11-30 01:01:00|
|    6    |    1     | 2016-11-30 01:11:00|
|    7    |    3     | 2016-11-30 02:21:00|
|    8    |    1     | 2016-11-30 02:31:00|
|    9    |    2     | 2016-11-30 03:02:00|
```

How or what query would it be where I could apply this logic
ADD the quantities of dsr WHERE its date_returned is greater than the first date_issued AND less than the following date_issued
that the result would be:

```
|    2    |
|    4    |  
|    2    |
```

The idea would be something like this:

```
|             dsr                         |
|  dsr_id | quantity |   date_returned    |
|    5    |    1     | 2016-11-30 01:01:00| --- This 1st and 2nd rows
|    6    |    1     | 2016-11-30 01:11:00| --/ will be added because
                                             the 1st date_issued is 
'2016-11-30 01:00:00' >= (the 1st date_returned) < '2016-11-30 02:00:00' which is the following date_issued

|    7    |    3     | 2016-11-30 02:21:00| --- Same idea for this two
|    8    |    1     | 2016-11-30 02:31:00| --/ Since its fits to the condition where this date_returned is just between 2nd & 3rd's date_issued

|    9    |    2     | 2016-11-30 03:02:00|
```

I know this could be easily done programmatically but I just want to know and learn how to do it in SQL and if it is easier in SQL.

Comment: what is the link between your 2 tables?? There should be a foreign key of sales table in the dsr table or the opposite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/OVXVD98166)**

```
SELECT start_date, end_date, SUM(D.quantity)
FROM (
        SELECT ds1.`sales_id`, 
               ds1.`date_issued` start_date,  
               COALESCE(ds2.`date_issued`, CURRENT_DATE) as end_date
        FROM ds as ds1
        LEFT JOIN ds as ds2
          ON ds1.`sales_id` = ds2.`sales_id` - 1
     ) R
JOIN dsr D
  ON D.`date_returned` >= start_date
 AND D.`date_returned` <  end_date
GROUP BY  start_date, end_date
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]